# Doom Emacs: Sly Vs. Slime issue

Tags: emacs, package

I have an org file with `source` block:

```
#+begin_src lisp
(defun palindromp (l)
  (equal l (reverse l)))
(palindromp '(a b c b a))
#+end_src
```

When I type `C-c C-c` to evaluate this block, I get the following message.

```
org-babel-execute:lisp: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, sly
```

My Doom configuration (given by **r\hlissner**) is:

```
;; in ~/.doom.d/packages.el
(package! sly :disable t)
(package! sly-macrostep :disable t)
(package! sly-repl-ansi-color :disable t)
(package! slime)
```

Do I have to add anything more here in my configuration. I did

```
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("lisp" . slime))
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `org-eval-lisp-eval-fn` is `sly-eval`.

I changed it to `slime-eval`.  Now, it is working but requires slime to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Variable whose value is to be changed to "slime-eval" is named `org-babel-lisp-eval-fn`

instead of `org-eval-lisp-eval-fn` as written in the answer above. The variable is mentioned here: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-lisp.html